# Storing a string and a set in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I am trying to build a dictionary that contains unique words that appear in a input file as well as the line number of each unique word. This is what I have so far.

```
def unique_word_index():
    line_no = 0
    word_set=set()
    line_no_set=set()
    word_map = {}
    for line in input_file:

       word_lst=line.strip().split()
       word_lst=[w.lower().strip(string.punctuation) for w in word_lst]
       line_no += 1

       for word in word_lst:
           if word !="":
               line_no_set.add(line_no)
           if 'word' in word_map.keys():
                word_map['word']=line_no_set
           else:
                word_map['word']=''
```

Comment: Well, what are you asking?

Comment: How I should go about making a dictionary in the form of ['word': line_no]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
def unique_words(input_file):
    file = open(input_file)
    wordlist = {}
    dups = []
    copy = []
    for index, value in enumerate(file):
        words = value.split()
        for word in words:
            wordlist[word] = index
            dups.append(word)
    for word in dups:
        if dups.count(word) != 1 and word not in copy:
            del(wordlist[word])
            copy.append(word)
    for item in wordlist:
        print 'The unique word '+item+' occurs on line '+str(wordlist[item])
```

It adds all the values to a dict and to a list, and then runs to the list to make sure each value only occurs once. If not, we delete it from the dict, leaving us with only the unique data.

This runs as:

```
>>> unique_words('test.txt')
The unique word them occurs on line 2
The unique word I occurs on line 1
The unique word there occurs on line 0
The unique word some occurs on line 2
The unique word times occurs on line 3
The unique word say occurs on line 2
The unique word too occurs on line 3
The unique word have occurs on line 1
The unique word of occurs on line 2
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could go like this:

```
def unique_words(input_file):
    word_map = dict()
    for i, line in enumerate(input_file):
        words = line.strip().split()
        for word in words:
            word = word.lower().strip(string.punctuation)
            if word in word_map:
                word_map[word] = None
            else:
                word_map[word] = i
    return dict((w, i) for w, i in word_map.items() if i is not None)
```

It adds the words and their corresponding line numbers to the dictionary `word_map`. When a word is seen more than once, its line number is replaced by `None`. The last line removes the entries whose line number is `None`.

Now the compact version, that uses `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

def unique_words(input_file):
    words = [(i, w.lower().strip(string.punctuation))
            for i, line in enumerate(input_file) for w in line.strip().split()]
    word_counts = Counter(w for _, w in words)
    return dict((w, i) for i, w in words if word_counts[w] == 1)
```